# Import Error in zope.interface.registry in python

Tags: python, importerror, zope.interface

I am installing a project in virtual environment. I am getting error

```
from zope.interface.registry import Components
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named registry
```

Version of this module as 4.0.5

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("zope.interface").version
'4.0.5'
```

I tried the same on my machine (not virtual env),

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("zope.interface").version
'4.0.1'
>>> from zope.interface.registry import Components
```

Here `from zope.interface.registry import Components` didn't give any error. According to [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/3.8.0)

```
QUOTE: 3.8.0 (2011-09-22) 
New module zope.interface.registry. This is code moved from 
zope.component.registry which implements a basic nonperistent component registry 
as zope.interface.registry.Components.
```

, it should not give any error. Any suggestion what I'm missing here or how to solve this error ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this is a fresh virtualenv. Can you see the `registry.py` file in `ls lib/python*/site-packages/zope/interface`?

Comment: I had installed zope on system before installing project in virtual env. I checked the path of imported module (zope.interface) in my virtual and non-virtual env. Virtual `'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/interface/__init__.pyc'` and non-virtual is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope.interface-4.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/__init__.pyc`. Only under non-virtual location I can find `registry.py`

Comment: What does the `ls` command in the virtual env tell you is there? What does `import zope.interface;print(zope.interface.__file__)` say?

Comment: hi check again.. I have updated the comment

Comment: Ah, you are importing the system interfaces package, *not* one installed in a virtual environment. Are you certain you installed it? Do you run your virtualenv *without* system packages?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just ran command `virtualenv folder-name`

Comment: Right, this is Ubuntu (or Debian perhaps?) and it does fun things with `dist-packages` that I am not 100% certain about how it interacts with virtualenv. What it comes down to here is that the system-installed `zope.interface` is being used, *not* anything you installed in your virtualenv. Current versions of `virtualenv` make the `--no-site-packages` option the default, but you may want to use that option explicitly if your `virtualenv` is older (check `virtualenv --help` to see if the option is the default). I just *don't know* if `dist-packages` is supposed to be excluded or not.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error - I tryed to create new virtual env without site-packages. It creates all fine. But my ubuntu has already installed `zope.interface` for own use, so it did not want to install it additional to my venv.

This collision cause my venv to throw error in simple test app under mod_wsgi:

```
     from zope.interface.registry import Components
ImportError: No module named registry
```

So I trying to remove `zope.interface` from base python. But unistall command not removed it(i found  in google, that it is known problem).

Than i found solution: I just switched to my venv and give command for "upgrading" `zope.interface` from there:

```
(env)user@ubuntu:~/env$ sudo pip install --upgrade zope.interface
```

After this my problem with `zope.interface` dissmiss.

Your problem is similar, so my solution could help. Anyway this answer is very useful for ubuntu desktop users.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still having same issue, try this:

```
apt remove --purge certbot
apt autoremove
apt clean
apt install certbot -u
```

Tested on 'Debian 11 (bullseye)' & 'Ubuntu 22.04'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and upgrading all repositories fixed the issue for me:

```
pip3 freeze --local | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -I {} pip3 install --upgrade {}
```