# zope.interface.registry ImportError for Pyramid on Travis

Tags: pyramid, travis-ci, zope

I'm having trouble working with Pyramid on travis; the zope.interfaces dependency doesn't work.

This has to be in **system python** or `--system-site-packages` because I'm using binary scientific packages (scipy).

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/authorization.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyramid.security import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/security.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_registry
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/threadlocal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyramid.registry import global_registry
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/registry.py", line 5, in <module>
    from zope.interface.registry import Components
ImportError: No module named registry
```

This is my current travis.yml:

```
language: c

install:
  - sudo apt-get install python-scipy python-pip
  - sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
  - sudo pip install .

script:
  - nosetests

after_success:
  - coveralls
```

The build log indicates that `zope.interface-4.1.2` has been installed.

Comment: Is it Ubuntu? As far as I remember Ubuntu's system python used to include crippled/old versions of some zope packages which often resulted in weird import errors when using system Python without virtualenv or buildout

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610423/import-error-in-zope-interface-registry-in-python

Comment: I tried that solution and it didn't work for me